# Javascript resulting in SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript on Codecademy, and after entering in my code to make a short contact list, it returns an error message of:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

Here is my code:

```
var friends = {
    var bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "1800 4 charity",
    };
    var steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: "1800 I have lots of jobs",
    };
};
```

Any help is greatly appreciated thanks :)

Comment: remove `var` and replace `;` with `,` inside `friends`

Comment: The `friends` object needs to look more like the inner objects: no `var` or semicolons inside.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need var if you are in an object.  Also be sure to get rid of trailing commas.

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: "1800 4 charity"
    },
    steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: "1800 I have lots of jobs"
    }
};
```

When dealing with JSON remember you are just creating lists of names and values.

The format is

```
var object = {
    nameOfProperty: value,
    nameOfAnotherProperty: value2
};
```

Remember you only need commas between values not at the end of the list and no semicolons within the object (because then JS thinks you're missing the rest!).

The tricky part is then objects within Objects but as you're exploring, using an object as a value is perfectly legal.  So start with the innermost objects and work your way out and you shoudl be fine.